# Prove that the Galois group is $D_{8}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> Prove that the Galois group of $x^{4}-2x^{2}-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $D_{8}$.

Note that the order of $D_{8}$ is $8$.

How would I find the eight automorphisms of this group? Or can I just use the order of $G(x^{4}-2x^{2}-2/\mathbb{Q})$ to show that its order is $8$?

If I show the order of the Galois group is $8$, is it sufficent enough to show that, since it's nonabelian and order $8$, it's isomorphic to $D_{8}$?

Comment: there's also the [Quaternion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) that has order $8$ and is non-Abelian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First prove that $x^4-2x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$. Then its Galois group is isomorphic to a transitive subgroup of $S_4$. That means it is isomorphic to either $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$, $(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^2$, $D_8$, $A_4$ or $S_4$.

If you are then able to show that the order of the Galois group is $8$, then it must be isomorphic to $D_8$.

---

Slightly more in line with your approach, you could note that up to isomorphism there are precisely two non-abelian groups of order $8$. They are $D_8$ and $Q_8$, the quaternion group of order $8$. But the latter is not isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_4$, so it cannot be the Galois group of $x^4-2x^2-2$.

Comment: I totally forgot about $Q_{8}$, thanks for the heads up on that. I understand now what to do, thanks so much.